# How to Navigate to an external URL using the HyperlinkButton in silverlight mvvm

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I'm using Silverlight 5 with mvvm pattern.
In xaml page I have one hyperlinkbutton and image. If I click that button named "Preview" means the image or anyfile has to be open in new tab browser.

XAML CODE:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
    <HyperlinkButton Content="Preview" Width="60" Height="26"   
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        TargetName="_blank"
        Name="HyperlinkButton"
        Background="Transparent"
        Click="HyperlinkButton_Click">
    </HyperlinkButton>
```

VIEWMODEL CODE:

```
void ChooseHyperExecute(object param)
{
    WebBrowser br = new WebBrowser();
    SampleViewModel dt = param as SampleViewModel;

    string ma = dt.String_Value;
    br.Navigate(new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, string.Format("./Images/{0}", ma)));

}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`HtmlWindow.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189809%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method:

```
void ChooseHyperExecute(object param)
{
    SampleViewModel dt = param as SampleViewModel;
    string ma = dt.String_Value;            
    var externalUri = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, 
        string.Format("./Images/{0}", ma));
    var absoluteUri = new Uri(externalUri, UriKind.Absolute);
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(absoluteUri, "_blank");
}
```